# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:2) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I tried to paste .xlsx file to `assets/files/` in vue, then I got this error

```
warning  in ./src/assets/files/example-format.xlsx

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

 @ ./src/assets sync ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.131:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

how I can solve it? thank you so much

Comment: Hey Ashtav, did you solve this issue, if yes can you please add an answer over here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Nilesh I use google drive instead

Comment: Okay, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Put .xlsx file into `public` directory, and then `<a href="/demo.xlsx">Download</a>`, if you just want to the other people download it